# can anyone explain this sentence in simple english?

Tags: sentence

sentence is "stocks offered a picture of contrast on thursday as the benchmark sensex snapped its four-day falling spell after the rajya sabha passed the historic GST bill on wednesday amid signs of strength in global markets"

Comment: I can, but a real explanation of it would also entail an explanation of the various financial terms and their implications, which is mostly off-topic for this site. Which makes me want to ask why you're interested in this particular sentence? Where did you find it, and what would a full explanation of it help you achieve? Or, perhaps you'd be happy with an explanation which left the financial terms opaque and just dealt with the sentence syntactically?

Comment: This would be a better question if you explained any specific points of confusion. Surely you recognize at least some words, and are capable of looking up any that are unfamiliar in a dictionary. By the way, if you are still learning English, it is better to post your questions on the site specifically for  [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com).

Comment: Interpretation requests (in fact, all criticism, discussion, and analysis of English literature) are out of scope and may be removed. [(more)](http://english.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score 2):

"Stocks" is a way of personifying the stock market.

"Offered a picture of contrast" is an overly-wordy way of saying the stock market changed direction.

"the benchmark sensex" refers to the SENSEX, a numeric index of stock marked performance. (See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BSE_SENSEX.)

"snapped its four-day falling spell": Reversed a falling trend.  That is, a trend towards lower stock prices was reversed: Stock prices started to rise.

"rajya sabha" is a lawmaking body in India.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rajya_Sabha.

"GST" is an initialism for Goods & Services Taxes.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goods_and_Services_Tax_Bill.

"GST Bill" refers to a new bill that would decrease financial pressure on businesses doing commerce in Inida.  See http://indianexpress.com/article/business/gst-bill-goods-and-service-tax-bill-arun-jaitley-here-is-how-india-inc-is-reacting-rajya-sabha-2951877/.

"amid signs of strength in global markets" would indicate various financial indicators that indicate a robust (i.e., growing) economy.

In summary: The indications of a stable or growing economy led India to pass a tax bill that indicated confidence in the economy, and that helped reverse a trend in falling stock prices.

Comment: Well done, and simply.